# Roblox Lua: I can't do arithmetic in the middle of print()

Tags: variables, math, lua, roblox

I am trying to put `Rich` as a variable, in the middle of `print("You are" + print(Rich + 1) + "Rich")`. It's inside a function so that whenever the player makes a part, which is going to be money in this case, their richness goes up by one:

```
    function createPart()
        local Rich = 0 
        local myPart = Instance.new("Part")
        print("You are" + print(Rich + 1) + "Rich")
        myPart.Transparency = 0.5
        myPart. Anchored = true
        myPart.Position = Vector3.new(0,0,0)
        myPart.CanCollide = true
        myPart.Name = "lol" -- how to name a part after instance.new
        myPart.Parent = game.Workspace 
    end
    createPart()
```

I am stuck with that. Could I get an explanation as to how it would work?

Comment: if you would read the Lua manual you would know that `print("You are" + print(Rich + 1) + "Rich")` is nonsense in pretty much any thinkable way. Learning Lua's very basics befor trying to use it for Robolox development would make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to increase the variable, you have to store it at a higher scope, otherwise it will be garbage collected at the end of the function call.

```
local Rich = 0
local function createPart()
    Rich = Rich + 1
    -- print out the message
    -- create the part
end
```

As for printing it out, you can accomplish this three different ways :

1) comma separation.

The `print()` function accepts any number of arguments, and will put their values together.

```
print("You are", Rich,"Rich")
```

2) string concatenation

In lua, the `..` operator is used for string concatenation, not the`+` operator.

```
print("You are" .. tostring(Rich) .. "Rich")
```

3) string formatting

The lua string library allows you to format your strings by specifying where variables should go in the string. %d can be used to represent an integer.

```
print(string.format("You are %d Rich", Rich))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're very close to your own solution. There are just a couple of mistakes in your attempt. The first is that you need a way to track the player's 'Richness'.

If you want this to appear in the Leaderboard at the top right, you need to attach a 'leaderstats' Value to the player. You can do this by doing the following:

```
-- somewhere in code, connect to the PlayerAdded event.
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- in here, add a folder named 'leaderstats' to the Player. 
    -- IMPORTANT: It must be named 'leaderstats' exactly, all lowercase
    local leaderstats = Instance.new('Folder')
    leaderstats.Name = 'leaderstats'

    -- then add the Richness to the added Player. Name if whatever you'd like
    local richness = Instance.new('IntValue')
    richness.Name = 'Richness'
    richness.Value = 0

    -- Parent this Richness value to the leaderstats to make it appear
    -- in the Leaderboard at the top right
    richness.Parent = leaderstats

    -- After you've created this Leaderboard stat, you need to 
    -- parent the leaderstats to the Player
    leaderstats.Parent = player
end)
```

Now all players will show up on the Leaderboard with a 'Richness' stat. They'll all be 0 until you update this value. You can update the value using `RemoteEvent`s from the Client to the Server.

---

The Second is that you are printing to the Output window incorrectly. When you merge strings together (called concatenation), in Lua you do so by using '..'. For example:

```
print('Here is a ' .. 'part of a ' .. 'string')
```

This will output the following in the 'Output' window:

```
Here is a part of a string
```

So to put that into use in your code, you'd type the following:

```
print('You are ' .. (Rich + 1) .. ' Rich')
```